# jQuery get textbox value from owl carousel current slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider, owl-carousel

I am using `owl carousel` jQuery image slider and I want to get textbox value from current slider. I have added click event to get textbox value from current slider but don't know how to read from that.

Any idea how to this?

Here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8bJUc/575/

### HTML:

```
<div id="dino-example" class="dino-carousel">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://johntomsett.files.wordpress.com/2014/03/14525_1_v12_tp.jpg" alt="dinosaur1"></img>
    <input type="text" class="inv" value="1">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://images.clipartpanda.com/t-rex-dinosaur-clip-art-T-Rex-Dinosaur_1.png" alt="dinosaur2"></img>
    <input type="text" class="inv" value="2">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQbuwkU3kDpr4rByYQ3ydbTPv6zP1L0yhrKB00fa5YhkY0i9WKFWA" alt="dinosaur3"></img>
    <input type="text" class="inv" value="3">
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="http://content.animalnewyork.com/wp-content/uploads/new-dinosaur-nasutoceratops.jpg" alt="dinosaur4"></img>
    <input type="text" class="inv" value="4">
  </div>
</div>

<div>
  <a href="#" class="get">Get value from textbox</a>
</div>
```

### jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#dino-example").owlCarousel({
    items: 5,
    singleItem: true
  });

});

$(document.body).on('click', '.get' ,function(){
    alert('hey');
});
```

Comment: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/f43waf7j/)

Answer (score 0):

class active is added to owl page icons when they are clicked. you can get the index of active element to target current slide:

```
var owl_item =  $('.owl-item');
$(document.body).on('click', '.get' ,function(){
   var selectedindex = $('div.active').index();
   alert(owl_item.eq(selectedindex).find(':text').val());
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4q45d9t6/)**

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/8bJUc/576/)**

Make use of `afterMove` option of `owlCarousel` and set `active` class to the current active `element` and then on `click` find the `element` with active `class` as below:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dino-example").owlCarousel({
    items: 5,
    singleItem: true,
    afterMove: function (elem) {
      $(".owl-item").removeClass('active'); //remove it from every item
      var current = this.currentItem; //get currentItem
      $(elem).find(".owl-item").eq(current).addClass('active'); //add active class
    }
  });
  $(".owl-item:first").addClass('active'); //add active class to first owl-item on DOM ready
});

$(document.body).on('click', '.get' ,function(){
    var ipVal=$(".owl-item.active").find('input[type=text]').val();
    //find input present in active item and get its value
    alert(ipVal);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the owlCarousel API, which is pretty neat. And it can get the job done in 1 or 2 lines.

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.get' ,function(){
  var dino = $("#dino-example").data('owlCarousel');
  alert($($('.owl-item')[dino.visibleItems]).find('input[type=text]').val());
});
```

In the first line, we assign data for the carousel to a var name 'dino'. In the second line, depending upon your class name for the item and considering you are displaying 1 per slide. We get the 'visibleItems' array's first item and look for the text field with value.

Hope that helps!